# Split a String into Pieces

Tags: java, string, split

I'm trying to split a string into different parts each having x amount of characters in it. How can I go along doing this?

**EDIT:** I've managed to figure itout thanks to @amith down below however I'm unsure how to make it not split words, any ideas?

Thanks,
- Exporting.

Comment: Have you heard about String.split() method ?

Comment: @Rehman yes but Im not too sure how to use it in this case, I've only used it to split a String into an array without character limits.

Comment: Post your input and expected output

Comment: @Rehman Im simply just trying to split a string I have to provide x amount of characters on each line.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> splitString(int interval, String str) {
    int length = str.length();
    List<String> split = new ArrayList<>();
    if(length < interval) {
        split.add(str);
    } else {
        for(int i=0;i<length;i+=interval) {
            int endIndex = i + interval;
            if(endIndex > length) {
                endIndex = length;
            }
            String substring = str.substring(i, endIndex);
            split.add(substring);
        }
    }
    return split;
}
```

This is a sample code to split string at regular intervals

Comment: How would I be able to prevent it splitting words in half though?

Comment: May be you can just call with half of the String using subString()

Comment: whatya mean? Mind showing an example?

Answer (score 0):

If `result` is an array of `char`, try this:

```
public static char[] split(String str, int numChar) {
    char[] s = str.toCharArray();
    if (numChar >= str.length()) {
        return s;
    }
    char[] r = new char[numChar];
    System.arraycopy(s, 0, r, 0, numChar);
    return r;
}
```

Or if `result` is a `String`, try this:

```
public static String split(String str, int numChar) {
    char[] s = str.toCharArray();
    if (numChar >= str.length()) {
        return String.copyValueOf(s);
    }
    char[] r = new char[numChar];
    System.arraycopy(s, 0, r, 0, numChar);
    return String.copyValueOf(r);
}
```

Please note that two of above methods do not change the original String.

Comment: How would I be able to prevent it splitting words in half though?